# Internet Explorer Lost File Associations

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I have a user that is trying to download files using 32 bit Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit. She clicks on the download hyperlink and then the Internet Explorer download file dialog is displayed with the Open, Save, and Cancel options. She clicks the dropdown button next to Save and then clicks on "Save As". At this point, she's presented with the standard Windows Save As dialog. However, instead of the file name being the correct name of the file, it's the URL of the opening page. The Save As Type only has the option of `All Files (*.*)`. If you try to save anyways, then Internet Explorer fails to download it, the error message in the download manager is "could not download this file".

If I use my own computer and try to click the same hyperlink, then I get the proper file name and the Save As Type displays the correct file type, for example `Microsoft Word Document (*.docx)`.

This problem occurs with any file she tries to download with Internet Explorer. Verified with .mp4, .xlsx, and .docx files.

File associations on her computer appear correct. Double clicking any file in Windows Explorer opens the correct program.

Is there a setting in Internet Options or a Registry setting I'm overlooking that might cause this?

Comment: I suggest downloading IE11 update, install it, this should resolve the user's corruption problem.

Comment: @Ramhound IE 11 is not an option. We have found many incompatibilities with intranet web applications (that were written by 3rd parties so we can't fix them ourselves) so we have to stick with IE 10.

Comment: Alright.  So uninstall IE10 and/or repair the installation, because the installation is corrupt and thats the simplest solution.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I realize I can probably fix it that way, but it's just avoiding the problem. I'd like to find the root cause, so if the issue recurs I can handle it properly.

Comment: Its possible the corruption has existed for awhile. I would take an image of the hdd so you can compare if the reinstallation works.  Do other browsers exihbit this problem?

Comment: @Ramhound If you want to create an answer saying to reinstall IE, I'll mark it as accepted. That's what I ended up doing and it worked.